# libcurl get in mem example .exe only runs in mingw64/bin folder

Tags: c, gcc, libcurl, mingw-w64

I am new to c and am trying to run the GET in memory example from https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html.

I tried searching for similar questions here on S.O. and elsewhere but did not come up with much that has helped.

When I create the .exe file using "gcc -o curl_ex curl_inMem.c -lcurl" the .exe will only run successfully if I place it inside the C:\msys64\mingw64\bin folder.  (Where the libidn2-0.dll file is located).

When I try to run it from my project folder (or any other folder) I get "The procedure entry point DllMain could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libidn2-0.dll".  If I place the .exe file inside the mingw64\bin folder it runs normally.

[image: The error when running from outside the mingw64\bin folder]

Here is the C code, it is essentially the example copy pasted with a different URL and printing the response body.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};
 
static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;
 
  char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(!ptr) {
    /* out of memory! */
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }
 
  mem->memory = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
 
  return realsize;
}
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;
 
  struct MemoryStruct chunk;
 
  chunk.memory = malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
  chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */
 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
 
  /* init the curl session */
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
 
  /* specify URL to get */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=CYYC&hoursBeforeNow=1");
 
  /* send all data to this function  */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
 
  /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
 
  /* some servers do not like requests that are made without a user-agent
     field, so we provide one */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
 
  /* get it! */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
 
  /* check for errors */
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */
    printf("%s\n", chunk.memory); // Print the response body to stdout
    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (unsigned long)chunk.size);
  }
 
  /* cleanup curl stuff */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
 
  free(chunk.memory);
 
  /* we are done with libcurl, so clean it up */
  curl_global_cleanup();
 
  return 0;
}
```

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Good job on asking a clear question.  How do you build the program?  I suspect it can't find dll but I don't know anything about windows.

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for responding so quickly.  I was using "gcc -o curl_ex curl_inMem.c -lcurl" from a command line in the project folder.  I changed this to "gcc curl_inMem.c -o curl_ex.exe -lcurl" and moved the C:\msys64\mingw64\bin PATH entry to first in the list.  Now my builds seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the PATH entry for C:\msys64\mingw64\bin to first in the list and now my builds seem to work from any folder.  I found this by running an automated build via VSCode and it worked as expected (VSCode used full paths for everything). (I think maybe another C compiler is installed on this machine?)

I also noticed that the order of parameters passed to gcc command was different.I decided to try and match what VSCode used (again, very new to C). I originally had as a build command "gcc -o curl_ex curl_inMem.c -lcurl".  I changed that to "gcc curl_inMem.c -o curl_ex.exe -lcurl".

With those changes, the builds seem to be running as expected.

Thank you to all that looked in on this.  Sorry to take up time with a "noob" question.